# Close popup (div) jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a div which appears when a textbox gets focus. DIV has *n* number of textboxes. I want to say display:none when a user Clicks anywhere in the window. Div should not close if the user is switching between textboxes.

All these jquery plugins, say the calendar control closes if user clicks outside. How is that happening? Any idea?

Comment: Hi,
 There is a problem. The example above is good but doesnt work quite well for me. I have a div with 2 textboxes in it and those text boxes keep on changing. all they share is same class. So I have to figure out some jquery solution. 


The problem with the above approach is that when i click inside one of the textboxes inside the div, it still considers it as clicked out of the div which is not wt i want.

> I wonder how all the date popups work.
> Thats exactly what I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to tell if an Outside Element was Clicked with Javascript](http://blog.josh420.com/archives/2007/11/determine-if-any-other-outside-element-was-clicked-with-javascript.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You would achieve this using a Modal Dialog implementation.